# Known moderate severity security vulnerability detected in ejs < 2.5.5

Tags: node.js, github, xss, ejs

I got this alert for a few projects on GitHub:

> We found a potential security vulnerability in one of the dependencies
>   used by a repository that you contribute to.
>
> Known moderate severity security vulnerability detected in ejs < 2.5.5
>   defined in package.json. package.json update suggested: ejs ~> 2.5.5.

I can get rid of the warning by making the recommended update in `package.json`, and a `npm update` seems to work without problems. But I am a little bit reluctant to begin messing with the production servers.

The vulnerability is **https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2017-1000188** created 11.16.2017. In the alerted projects `ejs` is used by `express` and `express` is only used along with `sequelize`.

Does any one have insight about this vulnerability? How would XSS be possible in a scenario where `ejs` is used static and internally by `express`? Are there any real use case where `ejs` -> `express` -> `sequelize` can be vulnerable to a XSS attack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CVE links to [this commit](https://github.com/mde/ejs/commit/49264e0037e313a0a3e033450b5c184112516d8f) that followed [an earlier commit](https://github.com/mde/ejs/commit/3d447c5a335844b25faec04b1132dbc721f9c8f6#diff-0d9afaa7ce3db4d8cac4ca2abf3584ba) which stops some data variables from being passed into `renderFile` being converted into options that control EJS' behaviour. Looking back at [the EJS changes from 2.5.3 to 2.5.5](https://github.com/mde/ejs/compare/v2.5.3...v2.5.5), the list of allowed data that can be turned into configuration options was introduced.

This could be an issue if an Express app passed data into `render` directly from the client (like `req.params` or `req.body`) and malicious users could add the EJS options to any requests they send in via the `settings['view options']` object. My guess is one of those allowed you to inject content.

EJS also starts escaping the `filename` content in an error message for the 2.5.5 release that appears to be a quick fix before it can be properly escaped, which would seem to fit the XSS mould.  The whole error message would normally need to be escaped before rendering on a client though, and express does this for you if your using it's default, non production error handling.

I can't think how [Sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/) would be directly impacted by an XSS vulnerability, other than the requests you can cause via XSS.

Comment: Thanks. That cleared it more up! Had not seen the relevant commits. I believe I dont have to worry, the two node apps where I got the alert does nothing but passing JSON to and from a client via sequelize.

Comment: There was a recent [github issue](https://github.com/mde/ejs/issues/323) that looks to have highlighted the issue but it appears they scrubbed the info. Another pointing to [variable injection](https://github.com/mde/ejs/issues/225#issuecomment-269239743) but nothing completely definitive.